# MySQL: What Data type to use for YYYY field?

Tags: mysql, date, field, type-conversion

What Data type should I use to store YYYY date format (4 character year only, no months or days)?

Comment: Integer will be your friend.

Comment: @Tyr As you known Interger type cost 1, 2, 4, 8 bits, 2 minimum for a year, and YEAR type cost only 1 bit this is important  life time of your db. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you using integer(4)

Answer (score 1):

You need if you table exist add a column on your structure of the table :
example :

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name_to_alter` ADD `new_colum_name_year` YEAR NOT NULL AFTER `a_colum_name_exist`;
```

//YEAR NOT NULL the column is a type YEAR so XXXX only, and NOT NULL needed
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html